# Swift: how exactly do assets work for different sized devices?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a game that I made in Swift and I built it and all of its assets for the iPhone 5s. So naturally when built for a 4s or an iPad the game looks distorted and the image views are in the wrong place.

How do I get around this so that the game can work on both the 4/4s and 5/5s? Where do I put the smaller images? I see the 1x and 2x but what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Why don't you read [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html) [guides](https://developer.apple.com/high-resolution/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iPhone since the iPhone 4 in 2010 has a Retina Display. Now we have iPads with Retina Display, too.

You can have an asset named "image1.png" and a higher resolution version of the same asset named "image1@2x.png". Adding the "@2x" to the end of the file name, iOS knows which asset to use based on the current device's display.

Regarding your "So naturally when built for a 4s or an iPad the game looks distorted and the image views are in the wrong place" comment: what you want to pay attention to here is the actual screen size of the devise you're designing for.

The iPhone 4/4S has a screen resolution of 640 x 960 pixels, while the iPhone 5/5c/5s has a screen resolution of 640 x 1136. The iPad's screen resolution for Retina Display models is 2048 x 1536.

So, I think that your problem is not about creating the assets, but about how you arrange them on screen.

I'd recommend taking a look into an [AutoLayout tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Hope I've shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Thank you. AutoLayout fixed everything